# LuaJIT vs luac for custom Lua bytecode interpreter

Tags: lua, interpreter, bytecode, luajit

Related: [Differences between standard Lua bytecode and LuaJIT bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623052/differences-between-standard-lua-bytecode-and-luajit-bytecode)

I'm writing a Lua bytecode interpreter, and I'm trying to decide between LuaJIT and luac to generate the initial bytecode. Since I'm writing an interpreter, I'm not going to get any of the JIT performance, so it all comes down to the quality of the compiler and design of the generated bytecode.

Is either compiler significantly better?

I'm writing this in Dart (also interpreted), so any free optimization from the compiler is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest posting this to the [LuaJIT Mailing List](http://luajit.org/list.html). The people there including Mike Pall – the creator of LuaJIT – will provide a reasonably in-depth and objective analysis for you (or at least point you in the right direction).

Comment: Why are you writing your own byte code interpreter instead of using the one provided by Lua?

Comment: @lhf - Dart runs in the browser, that's the main reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go for LuaJIT bytecode. Mike Pall has written that compared to standard Lua bytecode, [LuaJIT bytecode is 40% smaller](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-06/msg01052.html). Also, Tim Caswell (contributor to node.js) has [announced](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.lua.general/95495) a new project called [brozula](https://github.com/creationix/brozula/), which allows you to convert LuaJIT bytecode into JavaScript and execute it in browser, so head over to the project site for some inspiration.